# Update a Db from a text file

Tags: c#, database, auto-update, talend

We have two tables in our database that need to be updated using an extraction of another source. This extraction provides us a text-file.

The first insert was easy thanks to Talend but now we have another problem.

We don't want to do a simple insert or update but we want to compare both sources and the give the choice to the user to select which values are good for each entry.

For the moment the only solution found is to insert the new content in another table and the to compare each entry thanks to the program, then we display the entries that have had modifications.

The problem is that we have 1500+ entries, and this solution has very low performances, so we're looking for a new one.

Would there be a solution like extrading from our db into a text file, then compare both files automatically and gerenate a third file including only the modifications. This third one would be easier to load in the program and to be analyzed.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Since your input are regular text files, I would use a [comparer software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96051/which-file-comparison-tool-can-handle-block-movement-and-multiple-revisions) - provided that your text file 'records' are always in the same order. Unless you are going to do this process many times, then it's probably better to write some specific program.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer,

My point is not to compare the files in the IT service, but to provide the questionnable data automatically to the software so that we can propose them to the users through the program in order to let them chose which data to keep

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only a few records (1500+) in the database:

- load all records from the database into memory,
- start reading every line in the updated input file
- see if there is an exact match with the records in memory
- if there is not, insert the record into the database with a link to the original db record

For your selects:

- If the 'link' column is empty it is an 'actual record'
- If there is a value in the link column, you can use that to select the records that need to be compared by the user

When your database becomes too large to load everything into memory, you'll have to switch to batch processing (using PL/SQL or T-SQL or...) or change the process somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But what do you mean by "load the entries into memory"?

Thanks again

Comment: I think the easiest way to go around this would be to create a typed `DataSet` and fill that. Esentially selecting all records from the database and storing them into a DataSet.DataTable (which is a collection of DataRows)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, what is the difference with our solution:

We currently load a list of entries from our two tables and then compare the entries with the same id.
What takes time is not getting the whole list, but the compareason (which is currently not very smart (we compare concatenations of strings), but still works) .

Then we return a table with only the "problematic entries" which conerns only few of them.

Once again, what takes time is the foreau(t_admin admin in admins) loop

Comment: You'll have to measure what exactly is taking so much time. Perhaps you use an inefficient way of comparing for equality. Perhaps it's the string concatenation that's taking so long. Perhaps you are really doing more db call then you think. There are many possibilities. It's probably going to be some silly thing that takes up 80% of the time. Locate what it is and optimize that. Your approach in itself can be made pretty fast for 1500 records.

Comment: Try not to concatenate, when comparing in DB since index won't work if you concatenate (or you need to create custom index)